# Ant design table click on tabel cell

Tags: reactjs, antd

https://codesandbox.io/s/7mo0rvl971

Check this example. You guys can notice that we can click on the name because they use the  tag

How can I click the name and get the content. For example, I click the cell 'John Brown' and I get back string 'John Brown'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is that you set data-id on

```
<a data-id={text} onClick={this.onClick}>{text}</a>
```

Then

```
onClick = (e) => {
    console.log('Content: ', e.currentTarget.dataset.id);
  }
```

Comment: Another way to handle that: https://github.com/react-component/table/pull/27#issuecomment-172420963

Answer (score 4):

if you want to add a click event on a specific column, you can use `onCell` in your columns object.

```js
const table_columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        key: 'name',
        onCell: (record, rowIndex) => {
            return {
                onClick: (ev) => {
                    console.log(record, rowIndex);
                },
            };
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

In recent version, you can just use `useRow` property to set onCLick event. You can  see this here: https://ant.design/components/table/#onRow-usage

Comment: It works for row clicking. But not for cell.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Simple and Clear Answer

```
const columns = [
{
    title: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    render:text=><Link to='/detail'>{text}</Link>
}]

const data = [
{
    key: '1',
    name: 'Organisation',
    subType: 'Kindergarten',
    ville: 'Brusseis',
    email: 'info@example.com',
    telephone: '+32477070505',
}]
```

Comment: It's good practice on StackOverflow to add an explanation as to why your solution should work.